# Can I change the name of an existing index?

Tags: mongodb

I am undertaking an effort to produce drop/create scripts for our MongoDB deployment.  We would like to get to a place where all MongoDB database/collections are structurally identical across our dev, test, and production environments.  To this end, we have decided to name the indexes at ensureIndex time.  The problem is, how do I update the name of indexes that already exist?  What I know doesn't work is just re-running the ensureIndex with a "name" specified like....

```
// existing indexes, note its name is "groups_1"...
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.system.indexes.find();
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "groups" : 1 }, "ns" : "test.config", "name" : "groups_1" }
...

// attempt to change its name by re-issue ensureIndex command...
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.config.ensureIndex( { "groups" : 1 }, { "name" : "config_groups_ix" } );

// Nope, name is still "groups_1"...
dmReplSet:PRIMARY> db.system.indexes.find();
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "groups" : 1 }, "ns" : "test.config", "name" : "groups_1" }
...
```

How can I update the name of a mongo index that already exists?  Is there any risk in doing this?

Comment: I think you'd have to drop the existing index and then re-create it with your desired name.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping there is a better way.  Two of my production indexes are on a collection thats pretty big; 16 million docs and growing.

Comment: Ugh.  Just checked in with the 10gen guys.  @JohnnyHK is correct.  You can't rename and index in mongo.  You can only drop and recreate it.  Sigh.

Comment: I should add that Mongo 2.2 has this restriction.  Who knows what the future may hold.

Comment: There is now a feature request [SERVER-7337](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7337) for renaming indexes :)

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, this is impossible. The [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-an-index/) suggests to drop and recreate the index.

Update: This answer is still valid for MongoDB version 6.0.